# How to cancel Asynch task in below case

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-progressbar

Basically I have three function which execute three different queries and shows the list upon
OnSelection of corresponding radio button.

Before doing a database operation `PreExecute()` I hide list container and display progress bar spinning and on post execute vice versa.At any time user can click other radio button and select different list.

Now my problem is once asynch task is started I am not able to stop it Since I'm calling function inside asynch task. I could only check `isCancelled` before executing the function. Once function is invoked from asynch task I don't have control and function which is being called. Called function takes most of the time to execute. So how does I stop that function to execute upon `OnCancelled` - when user press another radio.

One possible solution would be to use different subclass of asynch task for each function/task. Or instead of calling function put entire code in do in background function

I would like to know better way of achieving this task.

Currently my code which does not work properly.

```java
public class ShopListView extends FragmentActivity {
    public static Location currentLocation;
    private static LocationTracker lTracker;
    private static final String TAG = "ShopListView";
    private GetList mTask = null;
    private String mIntent = "showPopular";
    ListView lview;
    boolean flagCategory = false;
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_shop_list_view);
        lview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        RadioGroup radioGroupListSelector = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radio_group_list_selector);
        radioGroupListSelector.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                // checkedId is the RadioButton selected

                switch (checkedId) {
                    case R.id.radioPopular:
                        Log.i(TAG, "Popular Radio Button Selected");

                        if (mTask != null) {
                            mTask.cancel(true);
                            Log.i(TAG, "Canceling Current Task");
                        } else {
                            mTask = new GetList();
                            mTask.execute("showPopular");
                        }

                        break;
                    case R.id.radioAZ:
                        Log.i(TAG, "AZ Radio Button Selected");

                        if (mTask != null) {
                            mTask.cancel(true);
                            Log.i(TAG, "Canceling Current Task");
                        } else {
                            mTask = new GetList();
                            mTask.execute("showAZ");
                        }

                        break;
                    case R.id.radioCategory:
                        Log.i(TAG, "Category Radio Button Selected");

                        if (mTask != null) {
                            mTask.cancel(true);
                            Log.i(TAG, "Canceling Current Task");

                        } else {
                            mTask = new GetList();
                            mTask.execute("showCategory");
                        }
                        break;

                    case R.id.radioNearBy:
                        Log.i(TAG, "NearBy Radio Button Selected");


                        if (mTask != null) {
                            mTask.cancel(true);
                            Log.i(TAG, "Canceling Current Task");

                        } else {
                            mTask = new GetList();
                            mTask.execute("showNearBy");
                        }
                        break;

                    default:
                        if (mTask != null) {
                            mTask.cancel(true);
                            Log.i(TAG, "Canceling Current Task");

                        }

                        showFeatured();
                        Log.i(TAG, "No Radio Selected");
                }
            }
        });

    }


    public void showFeatured() {

    }

    public ArrayList < String > showPopular() {
        flagCategory = false;
        ArrayList < String > list = new ArrayList < String > ();
        String sql = "select  S.shopName shopName from streetShopInfo AS S JOIN ratings AS R  where S.shopName=R.shopName and R.overall >0 order by S.shopName";
        Log.i(TAG, "Creating Adapter for Fetching Data");
        StreetFoodDataBaseAdapter mDBAdapter = new StreetFoodDataBaseAdapter(this);
        Log.i(TAG, "Adapter Ready..");
        Log.i(TAG, "Creating/Opening Database");
        mDBAdapter.createDatabase();
        mDBAdapter.open();
        Log.i(TAG, "Requesting info from getInfo function");
        list = mDBAdapter.getInfo(sql, "shopName");
        Log.i(TAG, "Information Retrived Passing it to SetView");
        //setView(list);
        mDBAdapter.close();
        return list;
    }

    public ArrayList < String > showNearBy() {

        flagCategory = false;
        ArrayList < String > list = new ArrayList < String > ();
        list = null;

        String sql = "select shopName shopName from streetShopInfo where distance<3";
        //currentLocation=lTracker.getLocation();
        Log.i(TAG, "Location Tracker Started");
        StreetFoodDataBaseAdapter mDBAdapter = new StreetFoodDataBaseAdapter(this);
        mDBAdapter.createDatabase();
        mDBAdapter.open();
        currentLocation = lTracker.getLocation();
        if (mDBAdapter.validDistance() && currentLocation != null && currentLocation.getLatitude() != 0) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Now Fetching Near By Location from DB");
            list = mDBAdapter.getInfo(sql, "shopName");
            Log.i(TAG, "Cursor Values Retrived into Array list");
            mDBAdapter.close();
        } else {
            if (currentLocation != null && currentLocation.getLatitude() != 0) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Location Received");
                mDBAdapter.updateDistance();
                list = mDBAdapter.getInfo(sql, "shopName");
                mDBAdapter.close();

            }
        }
        return list;
    }


    public ArrayList < String > showAZ() {
        ArrayList < String > list = new ArrayList < String > ();
        flagCategory = false;
        String sql = "select shopName from streetShopInfo order by shopName";
        StreetFoodDataBaseAdapter mDBAdapter = new StreetFoodDataBaseAdapter(this);
        mDBAdapter.createDatabase();
        mDBAdapter.open();
        list = mDBAdapter.getInfo(sql, "shopName");
        Log.i(TAG, "Cursor Values Retrived into Array list");
        //setView(list);
        mDBAdapter.close();
        return list;
    }

    public ArrayList < String > showCategory() {
        ArrayList < String > list = new ArrayList < String > ();
        flagCategory = true;
        String sql = "select  distinct category from streetShopInfo order by category";
        StreetFoodDataBaseAdapter mDBAdapter = new StreetFoodDataBaseAdapter(this);
        mDBAdapter.createDatabase();
        mDBAdapter.open();
        list = mDBAdapter.getInfo(sql, "category");
        Log.i(TAG, "Cursor Values Retrived into Array list");
        //setView(list);
        mDBAdapter.close();
        return list;
    }


    /*
     * Sub Class for Asynchronous Task
     */
    class GetList extends AsyncTask < String, Void, ArrayList < String > > {

        LinearLayout linlaHeaderProgress = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linlaHeaderProgress);
        LinearLayout linlaContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ListViewContainer);
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            linlaContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            linlaHeaderProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }

        protected ArrayList < String > doInBackground(String...params) {
            ArrayList < String > result = null;
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (params[0].equals("showNearBy") && !isCancelled())
                result = showNearBy();
            else if (params[0].equals("showPopular") && !isCancelled())
                result = showPopular();
            else if (params[0].equals("showAZ") && !isCancelled())
                result = showAZ();
            else if (params[0].equals("showCategory") && !isCancelled())
                result = showCategory();
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            super.onCancelled();

            linlaHeaderProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            linlaContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            // ask if user wants to try again
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList < String > result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            linlaHeaderProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            linlaContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            if (result != null)
                setView(result);
            else
                Toast.makeText(ShopListView.this, "Sorry Your Location not available..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your `doInBackground` inner code inside this:

```
while (!isCancelled()) {
    // your doInBackground code
}
```

Comment: It will check status before executing  inner function .Main problem is once inner functions starts to execute controll is passed to from while loop.And inner function takes more time. I want to cancel executing that function